# Cypress: cy.get() vs cy.contains(). Why do I get different results?

Tags: dom, automated-tests, cypress

I am having some issues when I am running these two commands:

- cy.get('prj-ui-menu').contains('Evidences')
- cy.contains('prj-ui-menu','Evidences')

First one works perfectly but the second one fails because it doesn't fetch any 'prj-ui-menu' element. Why is that? I understand the element yielded could be different, but working in the first case and not in the second is what I am not understanding. Any idea why could be this happening?

I tried reading docs in Cypress but I didn´t get any clue there. Only why one element or another would be yielded.

UPDATE 23/02:
I am adding html for more insight

```
<prj-ui-menu>
    <button class="prj-tab" role="tab">
        <div class="prj-tab-mobile">
            <div class="prj-content-mobile">
                <div class="prj-text-label">
                    Evidences
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prj-tab-desktop">
            <div class="prj-content-desktop">
                <span class="prj-text-label">
                Evidences</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prj-indicator">...</div>
        ▼<span class="mdc-ta">
            ::before
            ::after
        </span>
    </button>
</prj-ui-menu>
```

Comment: If you run Agof's code, both tests pass so clearly that's not what you have. Any chance you could post the HTML you have? Just the part inside `<prj-ui-menu>`.

Comment: Hi @Jhaidel, it is what you said. Second code is failing. After getting the html part I see there are two literals with Evidence content but, should it make any difference?? Thanks

Comment: I tested the HTML you posted, I don't have an answer but here is my observation: `cy.get('prj-ui-menu').contains('Evidences')` yields `<button class="prj-tab" role="tab">` which is surprising, I would expect it to give `<div class="prj-text-label">`. When I try `cy.contains('prj-ui-menu','Evidences')` I get `<prj-ui-menu>` which is to be expected.

Comment: So, I have a question - why do you consider `cy.contains('prj-ui-menu','Evidences')` to fail? Is it because you need a clickable menu item? I don't understand, since both expressions pass in the Cypress test runner - what exactly is failing?

Answer (score -2):

[When using `cy.contains()` with a selector, it yields the selector matched, and not the child element which matches the `contains` search.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Specify-a-selector-to-return-a-specific-element)
Consider the following DOM:

```
<html>
  <prj-ui-menu>
    <div>"Evidences</div>
  </prj-ui-menu>
</html>
```

When running `cy.get('prj-ui-menu')`, Cypress yields that `prj-ui-menu` element.

When running `cy.get('prj-ui-menu').contains('Evidences')`, the `cy.get()` command yields the `prj-ui-menu` element, which is used as the parent for `cy.contains()`, which yields the `div` underneath `prj-ui-menu`.

When running `cy.contains('prj-ui-menu', 'Evidences')`, Cypress yields the `prj-ui-menu` element, as that is the selector we've specified, and it (or a child element) contains "Evidences".

Comment: Whilst this is correct, it does not answer the question - why does the second statement fail.

Comment: It does answer the question from the title - "Why do I get different results?"

Comment: It pays to read the whole question. He also says "I understand the element yielded could be different" - so I guess the answer you gave is already known.

Comment: It is what Jhaidel said but thanks for answering agoff